# Can I use Redis Cache on a Shared Hosting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, caching, redis

I am working on a site using `Asp.Net MVC` which will be used for selling/buying Products. To improve performance, i wanted to store Products in cache and refresh it if that product get updated. I will certainly use this cache for other things as well where I feel.

The best cache service i see is `REDIS` but, as per my little understanding, it needs a separate server.

My site will be deployed on a shared hosting [ARVIXE](http://www.arvixe.com/). Can I use REDIS cache here? May be by creating a sub-domain?

If thats not possible, what would be your recommendations.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a 'separate server'. You need a REDIS server. Where/how such is obtained is off-topic.

Comment: Redis does not require a separate server as such. You would of course need to host it somewhere. There should be no issues with hosting it with ARXIVE. Also keep in mind that Redis performs noticeably better on a Linux hosted instance as its been optimized for it, but my guess is for your purposes you won't notice much of a difference in performance.